# link_to update boolean ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, link-to

I have a namespaced route that looks like:

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :feedbacks do
    put :process
  end
end
```

and a controller that looks like:

```
def process
  @feedback = Feedback.find(params[:id])
  @feedback.processed = true
  @feedback.save
end
```

and im generating a `link_to` that looks like

```
= link_to("Unprocessed", admin_feedback_process_path(feedback), :method => :put, :remote => true)
```

However I'm getting a wrong number of arguments error that looks like

```
Started PUT "/admin/feedbacks/2/process" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-05-16 12:36:05 -0700

ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)):
  app/controllers/admin/feedbacks_controller.rb:56:in `process'
```

What is the correct number of arguments to pass, or how should I re-write my controller in the route?

Thanks!
-alex

EDIT:1

running `rake routes` looks like:

```
admin_feedback_process PUT    /admin/feedbacks/:feedback_id/process(.:format) admin/feedbacks#process
```

Comment: sorry, that was a typo in my question, I'll fix and add the output of my rake routes

Comment: I guess it should be `= link_to("Unprocessed", admin_feedback_process_path(@feedback), :method => :put, :remote => true)`

Comment: Try @feedback = Feedback.find(params[:feedback_id])

Comment: @Pavan, I am calling this within a loop where '@feedbacks do |feeback|` scoped the variable correctly.

Comment: You should include that in the question!

Comment: @Iceman, same error...

Comment: also, worth mentioning, that now whenever i go to any route within feedback IE /admin/feedback I get `wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)` error. Is my name "process" bad?

Comment: Try to change it something else and see, 'Process' is a reserved word in Rails, not sure about 'process', could be reserved by some gem you're using, not sure.

Comment: @Iceman, I think you are correct, I;ve changed it to look more like processfeedback and I am making more progress

Answer (score 1):

I've got it working. "process" was a reserved word in Rails thanks to @Iceman for pointing that out. I went with the action called `processfeedback`, which has solved my problem